# Can *args be used after a keyword argument

Tags: python

I have a function which calls another function using a kwarg to determine if it should be called:

```py
def a(val):
    print(val)

def caller(func, call_it=True, *args, **kwargs):
    if call_it:
        func(*args, **kwargs)

# doesnt work
caller(a, 1)

# works
caller(a, True, 1)
```

How can this be handled where the `call_it` argument has a default value but *args are still needed?

Answer (score 5):

No, keyword arguments cannot precede normal arguments. A valid signature would be `caller(func, *args, call_it=True, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Is this valid in Python 2 as well?

Comment: It seems that it is not.

Answer (score 1):

No. A function signature looks like:

```
def funcname(req_positional, *args, named_keyword, named_keyword_with_default=None, **kwargs):
    # function body
```

You can sub some of those out if you don't need to reference them, for instance:

```py
def funcname(a, b, c, *, must_be_a_keyword_argument):
    pass

>>> funcname(1, 2, 3, 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: funcname() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
>>> funcname(1, 2, 3, must_be_a_keyword_argument=4)
>>>
```

See the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) for a more formal description

Comment: Isn't `optional_positional_with_default` a keyword argument?

Comment: @DanielWalker ah you're totally correct of course. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the function signature to

```
def caller(func, *args, call_it=True, **kwargs):
    ...
```